# Can I do fork twice in the same project in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, fork

I work in 1 project with others in gitlab. But for some reason can I fork twice to one project?

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple forks. However, the destination for the fork must be unique. So, if you want multiple forks, you will need to use a different name or namespace for the target.

If you just want to [update your fork](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2016/12/01/how-to-keep-your-fork-up-to-date-with-its-origin/), you can either pull the upstream changes in (see also: [mirroring](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/)) or move/delete your fork and fork the upstream project again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The button to fork a project is unavailable when you already have a fork. To fork your project again:

1. In the project you forked into, go to settings > general > advanced > "remove fork relationship".
2. Now go to the source project and the button to fork is available again.

Answer (score 0):

You can fork a repository as many times as you want, and then name the repo whatever you want, but you probably only want to do it once.